# snakemake rules: Passing on variables outside of the file name

Tags: snakemake

So far I used snakemake to generate individual plots with snakemake. This has worked great! Now though, I want to create a rule that creates a combined plot across the topics, without explicitly putting the name in the plot. See the `combined_plot` rule below.

```
topics=["soccer", "football"]
params=[1, 2, 3, 4]

rule all:
  input:
    expand("plot_p={param}_{topic}.png", topic=topics, param=params),
    expand("combined_p={param}_plot.png", param=params),

rule plot:
  input:
    "data_p={param}_{topic}.csv"
  output:
    "plot_p={param}_{topic}.png"
  shell:
    "plot.py --input={input} --output={output}"

rule combined_plot:
  input:
    # all data_p={param}_{topic}.csv files
  output:
    "combined_p={param}_plot.png"
  shell:
    "plot2.py " + # one "--input=" and one "--output" for each csv file
```

Is there a simple way to do this with snakemake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the code below should be more straightforward as it replaces the lambda and the glob with the `expand` function. It will execute the two commands:

```
plot2.py --input=data_p=1_soccer.csv --input=data_p=1_football.csv --output combined_p=1_plot.png
plot2.py --input=data_p=2_soccer.csv --input=data_p=2_football.csv --output combined_p=2_plot.png
```

---

```
topics=["soccer", "football"]
params=[1, 2]

rule all:
    input:
        expand("combined_p={param}_plot.png", param=params),

rule combined_plot:
    input:
        csv= expand("data_p={{param}}_{topic}.csv", topic= topics)
    output:
        "combined_p={param}_plot.png",
    run:
        inputs= ['--input=' + x for x in input.csv] 
        shell("plot2.py {inputs} --output {output}")
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a working version, by using a function called 'wcs' as input (see [here](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/advanced.html)) and I used `run` instead of `shell`. In the `run` section I could first define a variable before executing the result with `shell(...)`.

Instead of referring to the files with `glob` I could also have directly used the `topics` in the lambda function.

If anyone with more experience sees this, please tell me if this is the "right" way to do it.

```
from glob import glob

topics=["soccer", "football"]
params=[1, 2]

rule all:
  input:
    expand("plot_p={param}_{topic}.png", topic=topics, param=params),
    expand("combined_p={param}_plot.png", param=params),

rule plot:
  input:
    "data_p={param}_{topic}.csv"
  output:
    "plot_p={param}_{topic}.png"
  shell:
    "echo plot.py {input} {output}"

rule combined_plot:
  input:
    lambda wcs: glob("data_p={param}_*.csv".format(**wcs))
  output:
    "combined_p={param}_plot.png"
  run:
    inputs=" ".join(["--input " + inp for inp in input])
    shell("echo plot2.py {inputs}")
```